# How to test @InjectReactive() of Vue-Property-Decorator on vue-test-utils?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-test-utils, vue-property-decorator

I am not sure how to provide the inject-reactive data when I mount the component. I don't need the exact solution, just a hint would be much appreciated.

Here is my parent component:

```js
@Component
export default class Preferences extends Vue {
  @ProvideReactive() serviceLevels: CarrierFilterType[] = [];
  // more code here...
```

Here is my child component:

```js
@Component
export default class CarrierFilters {
  @InjectReactive() readonly serviceLevels!: CarrierFilterType[];
   // more code here...
```

Here is my test file:

```js
// other imports are here...

import { supportedServiceLevels } from '../../constant';

// initial setup code here...

describe('Settings > Preferences > Content > CarrierFilters.vue', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    options = {
      localVue,
      i18n,
      store,
      router,
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      provide: { // I am not sure how to provide the inject-reactive data here...?
        serviceLevels: [...supportedServiceLevels],
      },
    };

    initWrapper = shallowMount(CarrierFilters, options);
  });
  // more code here...
```

Currently, I am getting the below console error when I run the test:

```
console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621
    [Vue warn]: Injection "__reactiveInject__" not found

    found in

    ---> <CarrierFilters>
           <Root>
```

By the way, the above code is working with the `@Inject` but not with the `@InjectReactive`. I have seen their source code, seems like I have to provide this key `__reactiveInject__` somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put all reactive properties inside `__reactiveInject__`. For example:

```js
const wrapper = mount(Component, {
  localVue,
  provide: {
    __reactiveInject__: {
      foo: "bar"
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: It does remove the warning but it doesn't pass the value to the Component. The value in this case `foo` is always undefined.

Comment: @ShamimHossain Interesting, it passes the value just fine for me... Try updating your packages or there may be a problem somewhere else in your project.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking for this for ages. How did you find out about this? I can't find any docs showing this.